# CakePHP 3 Datasource switch

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently trying to get my application to switch the datasource depending if it is going to write or read from the database. Unfortunatly I just can't get it to work. I'm guessing I am only missing something small. I've created an EventListener to catch the beforeSave event to switch the datasource when writing. But the actual switch doesn't work unfortunatly.

I dunno in CakePHP2 it worked like a charm :-D

Here is my current Listener:

```
<?php
namespace MasterSlaveManager;

use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Database\Query;


class MasterSlaveManager implements EventListenerInterface {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return [
            'Model.beforeSave' => 'beforeSave',
            'Model.afterSave' => 'afterSave',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave(&$event) {   
        $event->subject()->connection(ConnectionManager::get('master'));
    }

    public function afterSave() {

    }

}
```

I'm not even sure if I am currently if I am working in the right direction.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with, the context (where/when/how do you subscribe your listener and invoke saving?), the code required to reproduce the problem, your debugging attempts, and possible errors. Often the problem solves itself when collecting such information.

Comment: Ohh sorry I thought I had implied the problem in my post. Well I expect it to write to a different Datasource (master). Unfortunatly it writes to the default Datasource. The Listener is called. I have tested that just by returning the Event Object.

Comment: How does returning the event object indicate that the listener is being invoked?

Comment: Just so you know, what you're doing there, ie changing the connection at `Model.beforeSave`, works just fine over here.

Comment: @ndm sorry not return but output it. That way I know that it entered the beforeSave method.